# convert 3 dimensional matlab matrix to 3 dimensional column vector

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix, resize, reshape

Hi I have a 3 dimensional matrix that I am trying to convert the rows to columns and then stack all the columns to generate a vector that will have the three dimensions.

therefore, row 1 becomes column 1, row 2 becomes column 2 etc. And then, column 2 goes under column 1, column 3 under column 1 and 2. I also need to keep the dimensions the same

PV_power_output(:,:,K) below   is a 365 x 24 x 27 matrix, which should become a 8760x1 vector following the positioning sequence mentioned above

I am struggling with the coding of this

So far I have

```
PV_power_output(:,:,K) = real((Vmpp_(:,:,K).*Impp_(:,:,K))*inverter_efficiency)/1000; 

 permdims = 1 : ndims(PV_power_output); 
out = reshape(permute(PV_power_output, permdims),8760,1,[]);
```

However, on checking the elements in different positions, the above is incorrect and so any help would be great!

Comment: Did you try to transpose before reshape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your permute is wrong, because as it stands it's not doing anything:

```
permute(PV_power_output, 1:3) == PV_power_output
```

maybe you need:

```
permute(PV_power_output, [2 1 3])
```

I general I often find reshape difficult to follow (especially when you go back to the code three weeks later) so if performance is not critical then you could consider using a loop here instead for your 3d matrix.

You might think about a cell array instead of 3d matrix, and then your reshape is much more straight forward:

```
PV_power_output{K} = real((Vmpp_(:,:,K).*Impp_(:,:,K))*inverter_efficiency)/1000;

vector = reshape(PV_power_output{K},8760,1);
```

---

**Update:**

Perhaps try reshaping to 2D:

```
out = reshape(permute(PV_power_output, [2 1 3]), 8760,27);
```

And then you can access the Kth column vector as:

```
vector_K = out(:,K)
```

Comment: I have managed to get every element in the correct position using the code below. How can I modify the code to be able to "access" K = 2 and K = 3 of out

Comment: PV_power_output(:,:,K) = real(((Vmpp_(:,:,K).*Impp_(:,:,K))*inverter_efficiency)/1000); 

PV_out(:,:,K) =(real((Vmpp_(:,:,K).*Impp_(:,:,K))*inverter_efficiency)/1000)'; 
out = PV_power_output(:);